# INAV beeps enabling NAVPOSHOLD?

Tags: inav, gps

I'm running a 500cm frame with 11" rotors. It flyes but the navigation modes seem to be a tip  suprised, that INAV 3 seems to have some troubles, when I turn on the 3D GPS+baro position hold (NAVPOSHOLD). It beeps 3 times and does also drift away, but [the docs](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki/Navigation-modes#nav-poshold---Position-hold) don't mention anything about beeps. Has anybody an idea what the problem might be?

There is no obvious problem in the blackbox log (BTW can I get a full log of warnings?). All sensors calibrated properly and GPS 3D fix. Nav safe is green before takeoff.

Comment: Not a full answer by any stretch, but it might help direct your search to include "buzzer" as well as "beep", check out [this page](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/blob/master/docs/Buzzer.md) in the docs for the buzzer.

Comment: Well yes, but if you look for 'GPS' you don't get any infos if there is a bug or not? I guess it's not a arming sound, as the copter is already in air. Will see forward to get more live infos when setup FPV OSD.

Answer (score 0):

I continued with some experiments and didn't got this error messages again. Esp. I installed a VTX and FPV Cam to check my settings via OSD and noticed some issues:

- GPS ok and pos locked
- You can't start with NAV modes enabled (knew it before but anyway)
- re forced compass calibration and gyro calibration and checked against visual compass and virtual horizon
- Horizon is less stabilazation controll than Angle, not sure if you can mix it with NAV modes?